# Can I cache chef client download?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

At work we have a really slow bandwidth and I need to intensively create VM's that are provisioned with chef and preparing take long time to download chef client.

There is a way to cache it ?

edit:

Since I use Vagrant, I found to just save the box with chef client already installed.

But the bootstrap template work too

Comment: How do you install chef on thoose VM ? On any way you have a solution to use a local "repo" (http server). You just have to create your own template if you're bootstraping with knife.

Comment: I'm using `knife solo prepare` . So the idea is to serve the file through the host machine then with the bootstrap file, redirect the dns to my host ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](http://matschaffer.github.io/knife-solo/) you may replace knife solo prepare by a knife bootstrap.

You'll have to create your own templates depending on your architecture in

https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/

There's exemples inside, the main idea is to comment the call to opscode chef installer and to set the download location directly.

Default template is chef-full.rb

More doc [HERE](http://docs.getchef.com/knife_bootstrap.html#custom-templates)

Thanks coderanger for the link to github instead of a path.

Comment: Probably easier to just link to the bootstrap template directly: https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/chef-full.erb